# Google colab pro+ gpu memory

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu, google-colaboratory, training-data

Could any body guide me the GPU memory memory provide by Colab pro +. I have been using colab pro but my ram is getting crashed when i try to train my model. Does Colab Pro+ GPU provides more memory than colab pro. Colab pro provides 12-15 gb memory depends on the GPU type.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the image below to find the difference between Google `Colab Pro` and `Colab Pro+`.

[image]

As you can see, `Colab Pro+` provides more memory with better performance than other subscriptions.